# How redirecting to specific page after login spring-boot

Tags: java, redirect, spring-boot, spring-security

Can someone help me to solve my redirect problem. I am not able to redirected to a specific page using my select option. I have combed through most of the examples but it doesn't seem to work.

Login Page

```
<form class="myform" th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
        <div th:replace="common/layout :: flash"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select th:field="*{cert}" class="form-control input-lg" id="selectEl" >
                 <option value="#">Select a location</option>
<option value="location.htm">Location</option>
<option value="other.htm">Other</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1">@</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="LoginID" th:field="*{username}" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" />
            </div>
        </div>
           <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                <span class="input-group-addon form-wrapper" id="sizing-addon2">@</span>
                <input type="password" class="form-control showpassword" placeholder="Pin" th:field="*{password}"  aria-describedby="sizing-addon1"  />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default toggle" type="button">Show Pin</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkbox" /> <p class="login-caution">I have carefully read all instructions as well as programme requirements in the Admission Brochure and i here my accept any responsibility for any omission(s) or error(s) on my submitted form.</p>
            </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="btnCheck" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Login</button>
    </form>
```

Login Controller

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginForm(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    String referrer = request.getHeader("Referer");
    if(referrer!=null){
        request.getSession().setAttribute("url_prior_login", referrer);
    }
    model.addAttribute("programs", Program.values());
    try {
        Object flash = request.getSession().getAttribute("flash");
        model.addAttribute("flash", flash);

        request.getSession().removeAttribute("flash");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // "flash" session attribute must not exist...do nothing and proceed normally
    }
   return "login";
}
```

Security Config

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler())
                    .failureHandler(loginFailureHandler())
                    .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        }

public AuthenticationSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler() {
        //return (request, response, authentication) -> response.sendRedirect("/");
        return (request, response, authentication)-> {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getHeader("url_prior_logins"));
        };
    }
```